# A Python regex to find soccer team fixtures in string

Tags: python, html, regex, string

I am using the Requests module to access the HTML from my target website and then using Beautiful Soup to select a specific element on the website. The element in question is a table that contains the results thus far of the English Premier League 2016/2017 season. The table contains the match date, the teams involved, the full-time score and the half-time score. I want to use Python to parse the HTML of the table element and extract the fixtures listed on there. The teams are always listed as:

Team A - Team B

A team name can be 1-3 separate strings (e.g. Burnley, Manchester United, West Ham United.

My attempt so far is:

import re
teamsRegex = re.compile(r'((\w+\s)+-(\s\w+)+)')

My logic here is that the first team can be 1-3 separate strings in length and each string is always followed by a white space. Therefore, the pattern (\w+\s)+ represents a string of any length followed by a white space and can be repeated 1 or many times. The second team name will always begin with a white space following the "-" character and again can be a string of any length, repeated 1 or many times (\s\w+)+.

I'm sort of achieving the desired results but the above is not entirely correct. I am returned a list with my desired result at index 0 followed by the first string of index 0 as index 1, and the last string in index 0 as index 2.

Example string:

'Burnley - Swansea City align=center width=45> 0 - 1 align=center> (0-0)'

Regex finds:

[('Burnley - Swansea City', 'Burnley ', ' City'), ('0 - 1', '0 ', ' 1')]

I would just like it to find [('Burnley - Swansea City')]

Many thanks in anticipation of any help!

Comment: It is strange you get a piece of HTML inside the input string. You can try [`teamsRegex = re.compile(r'(?:[a-zA-Z]\w*\s)+-(?:\s[a-zA-Z]\w*)+\b(?!=)')`](http://ideone.com/HjuLTI) but I guess it would be best to fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r'(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\s)+-(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]*)+'
```

Here you have two non-capturing (`?:`, so you'll get the full match only) groups to match the teams' names. I chose to use letters explicitly, so the expressions only match words beginning with capital letters and exclude digits. You should change that if the teams' names can contain digits (like "BVB 09").

Depending on the HTML file's content one could add a final lookahead `(?= align)` to increase specifity.

**Edit:**
To match up to three capitals and optional '&'s, try this :

```
r'(?:[A-Z&]{1,3}[a-z]*\s)+-(?:\s[A-Z&]{1,3}[a-z]*)+'
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution and was appearing to work perfectly well until I realised there were a couple of team names that weren't captured correctly. They are:

1. QP Rangers (first 2 characters are capitalised).

2. Brighton & Hove

For this one, supposedly, the regex doesn't capture the '&' sign so it doesn't constitute a match.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to modify JosefScript's regex to also capture the above examples?

Many thanks is advance

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps.